# Which IP addresses do I enter in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: 14.04, server, network-manager, webserver

I am trying to setup a webserver with Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

I am struggling with the /etc/network/interfaces file.

This is my setup.

```
Router IP 192.168.1.254
Externel static IP 212.195.**.*5 (Blanked for security)
Webserver PC IP 192.168.1.67
```

I also have some details from my ISP

```
Static IP as above
Mask 255.255.255.255
```

And also some more details in my router.

```
DNS 
212.195.70.9 
212.195.70.10
```

I edited my /etc/network/interfaces like this..

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 212.195.**.*5
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        network 192.168.1.67
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.1.254
        dns-nameservers 212.195.70.9 212.195.70.10
```

When I save this file I loose internet connection after reboot. Which is telling me I am wrong.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`192.168.x.x` is a private network address. It appears that your "web server" is behind a NAT router which has an internal address of `192.168.1.254` and an external one with `212.195.x.x`.

If you would like to expose this host to the Internet, log in to the router administration interface and forward TCP port 80 to `192.168.1.67`. You do not need to add the external address to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

By the way, there is no such directive as `network` in the `interfaces(5)` manpage and using a broadcast domain of `192.168.0.x` while you are in the `192.168.1.x` network does not make sense. Try this instead:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.67
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Then let `/etc/resolv.conf` contain:

```
nameserver 212.195.70.9
nameserver 212.195.70.10
```

Comment: Great thank you for that I knew I would be reading into it more than I needed to. I have been reinstalling every time to start from scratch will give that a go later :)